# Why do I see the unicode character è when I type Alt-h in my xterm on CentOS?

Tags: linux, terminal, centos, tmux

I am sshing into a centos box from an ubuntu box. I keep seeing `è` when I type <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> (aka `M-h`). I want to use this key combo in tmux bindings but it doesn’t work because `tmux` doesn't recognize utf8 characters. I don’t have this problem on my Ubuntu box.

My wild guess is this is somehow related to locale. Here is my locale output on CentOS:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

I did notice that on Ubuntu I have an additional `LANGUAGE=en_US:en` line in my locale output.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just wondering...does pressing `Esc` followed by `H` cause the same character to be output?

Comment: @BenjiWiebe Esc H does not produce the same char

Comment: Hmmm... BTW, `Esc H` should be the key combo you want, if `Alt H` doesn't work you could use `Esc H`. But I understand that you want to know WHY `Alt H` doesn't work. And, to tell the truth, so do I. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
tput rmm
```

Seems to solve my problem.  Mostly.  But I don't entirely understand why.

When I run `infocmp` on my centos box I see that `rmm` and `smm` have values but they don't on my ubuntu box.  From the `terminfo` man page I learned that `rmm` "turns meta mode off" and `smm` "turns meta mode on".

Also it doesn't seem to work to add `tput rmm` to my .bashrc.  I have to manually run it from my centos shell.  Again I don't understand why.

Comment: Ubuntu's terminal database is farther in the past than CentOS (long story).  The upstream change was made in [2006](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_216), to match xterm.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off meta mode is part of the answer.  xterm has more than one configurable feature related to this.  The ncurses FAQ [Alt-keys do not work in bash](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#bash_meta_mode) provides some of the background.  Essentially, there are two notions of what *meta mode* is:

- xterm and the terminal database (terminfo) document the use of a meta key as a sort of shift-modifier, setting the eighth bit of an input byte.  xterm's manual has some notes on the topic in the section for the **[eightBitInput](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html)** resource.  The [terminfo manual](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Miscellaneous) is more succinct:

> If  the  terminal  has  a *"meta key"* which acts as a shift
>   key, setting the 8th bit  of  any  character  transmitted,
>   this  fact  can be indicated with **km**.  Otherwise, software
>   will assume that the 8th bit is parity and it will usually
>   be  cleared.  If strings exist to turn this "meta mode" on
>   and off, they can be given as **smm** and **rmm**.

- bash says it expects an escape character to prefix the character to which the meta key is applied.  (There is no record of how bash came to decide this, and that it was the *meta* key, but it goes back to the early 1990s at least).

So the problem is that xterm implemented a control sequence for turning meta mode on/off, and bash had some expectations about what to do with it.  The odd thing is that whatever terminal bash was prepared for was not noted (it certainly was not xterm).  However, just in case bash ever sees *that* terminal again, it turns on meta mode by default for any terminal which implements it.